# Prove that Neumann Boundary conditions allow for even reflection

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\cap \{x_n \geq 0\}$ be a domain with piecewise smooth boundary and suppose that $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1\left(\bar\Omega\right)$ is an eigenfunction of the Laplacian with Neumann boundary conditions. More precisely, assume that $$\Delta u = \lambda u \quad \text{in } \Omega$$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ and that $\partial_\nu u = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$. Define
$$
\tilde{u}(x_1, \dots, x_n)
=\begin{cases}
u(x_1, \dots, x_n) &\text{if } x_n \geq 0\\
u(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, -x_n) &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
on $\tilde{\Omega} = \Omega \cup \{(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, -x_n)\}: (x_1, \dots, x_n)\in \Omega$.

> I know that $\tilde{u}$ is an eigenfunction on $\tilde{\Omega}$. Where can I find a reference which proves this fact?

I'm looking for a reference (or proof!) for this widely used reflection method. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Isn't this just the [method of images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_images)? Just note that the wiki page doesn't have a huge amount of information, though various PDE books and fluid dynamics books comprehensively cover the topic.

Comment: @mattos Glad to have a name for it! I looked at some books (e.g. Evans) and I couldn't find a proof. I feel as though it should be simple, but I'd prefer a source with the proof for citation purposes

Comment: I think it might be in Habershams PDEs book? I'll try and find a book or some notes on it, I'll let you know when I come across something.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I can't find the book you mentioned (I tried googling it, nothing really comes up). Do you have a link that would help me find the book?

Comment: The answer I recently posted to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276993/schwarz-reflection-principle-for-harmonic-functions/4496797#4496797) gives a proof in the $\lambda=0$ case.